# Need help finding words in a vector

Tags: c++, vector

I have two vectors: `a` and `b`. I want to check if a word from `b` is findable in `a`.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<string> a = {"abcd", "efgh","ijkl"};
    vector<string> b = {"efg","mno"};

    for(int j = 0; j < b.size(); ++j) {
        if (find(a.begin(), a.end(), b[j]) != a.end()) {
            cout << b[j] << endl;
        }
    }  

    return 0;
}
```

I tried to do this: made a loop through the vector `a` and compare elements to each other. I expected the output `"efg"`, but it prints nothing.

What is the reason for it?

Comment: "efg" is not an element of the vector `a`, so why do you expect it to be found?

Comment: `"efgh" (a) != "efg" (b)`

Comment: @AdriaandeGroot because it is findable in "a".

Comment: fun fact: `stl::vector` isn't exactly the same thing as `std::vector`

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but the code in the question doesn't need the extra stuff that `std::endl` does. `'\n'` ends a line.

Comment: "[B]ecause it is findable in `a`" isn't actually true. The string `"efg"` is findable *in a string* inside of `a`, but the vector `a` doesn't contain the string `"efg"` itself. Like I say in my answer, any comparison of strings you make with `==` (which includes `std::find`) will do an *exact* comparison. It will compare the *whole* strings, not substrings. Or would you really consider e.g. `"efg" == "efgh"` (as `std::string` objects) to be true?

Answer (score 3):

> I tried to do this: made loop through the vector `a` and compare elements to each other.

Your idea is fine, but your approach needs some tweaking.  `std::find()` looks for an *exact* match, but `"efg"` does not exist as a whole element in `a`. You need to do a *partial* match instead, since `"efg"` is a *substring* of the `"efgh"` element in `a`.

You can use `std::find_if()` instead, using `std::string::find()` for the substring search, eg:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<string> a = {"abcd", "efgh", "ijkl"};
    vector<string> b = {"efg", "mno"};

    for(const string& substr : b){
        auto findSubStr = [&](const string &elem){
            return elem.find(substr) != string::npos;
        };
        auto iter = find_if(a.begin(), a.end(), findSubStr);
        if (iter != a.end()) {
            cout << "found " << substr << " in " << *iter << endl;
        } else {
            cout << "did not find " << substr << endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/u6MXwN)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude because I was keeping close to the OP's original code. But obviously your suggests will provide some added performance. I have updated my example

Answer (score 0):

All comparisons you make (explicitly or with `std::find`) will be done comparing the *whole* strings. You need to find *substrings*.

You could loop over the `a` vector, and then over the `b` vector, and for each element in `b` check if it can be found inside of the element of `a`:

```
for (auto const& a_string : a)
{
    for (auto const& b_string : b)
    {
        if (a_string.find(b_string) != std::string::npos)
        {
            // b_string found inside of a_string
        }
    }
}
```